# Windows Application without a Window

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms

I want to build an app which has no Window or no visible Window. Imagine an App which when it start you've got a Menu which comes as a Circle an you can move a wheel which is at the edge of this circle to choose some option.
Is this even possible in WPF or in another Framework for building Windows Applications?

regards Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following values on the `Window`:

```
<Window ...
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Background="Transparent">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The window will have no borders, only the content will be visible.